# Inject parameter in hardcoded tar command

Tags: linux, shell, tar, code-injection

I'm using a linux software solution that uses the tar command to backup huge amounts of data.
The command which is hardcoded into the binary which calls the tar is:

```
/bin/tar --exclude "/backup" --exclude / --ignore-failed-read -cvjf - /pbackup 2>>'/tar_err.log' |  split -b 1000m - '/backup/temp/backup.tar.bz2'
```

There is no chance to change the command, as it is harcoded. It uses bzip2 to compress the data. I experienced a strong performance improvement (up to 60%) when using the parameter --use-compress-prog=pbzip2 which utilizes all CPU cores.
By symlinking the bzip2 from /bin/bzip2 to the pbzip2 binary I tried to trick the software, however when monitoring the process it still uses bzip2 as I tink this is built into tar.

I know it is a tricky question but is there any way to utilize pbzip2 without changing this command that is externally called?

My system is Debian Sequeeze.

Thanks very much!

Comment: You may `chroot` the whole thing, putting in your "fake" `/bin/` a `tar` script that injects your additional parameter and forwards the task to the "real" `tar`, but the effort may not be worth the gain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Danger: ugly solution ahead; backup the binary before proceeding***

First of all, check if the hardcoded string is easily accessible: use `strings` on your binary, and see if it displays the string you said (probably it will be in several pieces, e.g. `/bin/tar`, `--exclude`, `--ignore-failed-read`, ...).

If this succeeds, grab your hex editor of choice, open the binary and look for the hardcoded string; if it's split in several pieces, the one you need is the one containing `/bin/tar`; overwrite `tar` with some arbitrary three-letter name, e.g. `fkt` (**f**a**k**e  **t**ar; a quick Google search didn't turn up any result for `/usr/bin/fkt`, so we should be safe).

The program should now call your `/usr/bin/fkt` instead of the regular `tar`.

Now, put in your `/bin` a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/tar --use-compress-prog=pbzip2 $*
```

call it with the name you chose before (`fkt`) and set the permissions correctly (they should be 755 and owned by `root`). This script just takes all the parameters it gets and call the real `tar`, adding in front of them the parameter you need.

---

Another solution, that I suggested in the comments, may be creating a `chroot` just for the application, renaming `tar` to some other name (`realtar`, maybe?) and calling the script above `tar` (obviously now you should change the `/bin/tar` inside the script to `/bin/realtar`).

If the program is not updated very often and the trick worked at the first try I would probably go with the first solution, setting up and maintaining chroots is not fun.

Comment: Very smart solution, thanks. I followed your instruction, found the --ignore-failed-read string, added the pbzip2 string, then a got warned that this action will change the filesize, ignored and tried to execute with the result: Segmentation fault. This is a really good try so what can we do to make the binary work again?

Comment: I explicitly said to modify *only* the `/bin/tar` string, and *only* ***overwrite*** the string, because inserting characters in the middle of the binary makes it nonfunctional (you change the offsets in the data segment, but you are not fixing the offsets in the code). If you made the backup, restore it first, otherwise try to restore the previous state of the binary with the hex editor.

Comment: Anyhow, didn't you find the `/bin/tar` string? Or, more simply, `tar` alone? (to have it shown by `strings` you have to change its minimum string length to 3)

Comment: Okay, sorry. I change it and the binary works again. However, now no archive is created at all. Calling the fkt from shell displays the correct tar answer. Strange. `"/bin/fkt" --exclude "/backup" --exclude /  --ignore-failed-read -cvjf - /root 2>>'/tar_err.log' |  split -b 1000m - '/backup/temp/backup.tar.bz2'` is the command now.

Comment: The tar_err.log prints: /bin/tar: Kompressionsoptionen schließen sich gegenseitig aus.
»/bin/tar --help« oder »/bin/tar --usage« gibt weitere Informationen. Which means that the compression methods won't work together? Strange.

Comment: Still, `fkt` is called, correct? So now the big problem is solved, you only need is to change the script, making it process the parameters correctly. I'm no bash expert you may create another question about how to write such a script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move /bin/tar to (say) /bin/tar-original

Then create a script /bin/tar to do whatever you want it to do.

Comment: This is a viable solution only if you don't plan to use `tar` for anything else on that machine - which is quite unlikely; also, every update to the `tar` package will overwrite your script (or, worse, will fail with some strange `dpkg` error).

Comment: Yes I thought about that too, but as Matteo said, it would cause incompatibility on almost everything else on my system. Thank you anyways.